# How to use stages from 1 ymal pipeline to 2 pipeline Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm working on a project where we have 2 pipelines. 1 pipeline is currently working as expected having 8 stages in it.

Now I want to write code for 2 pipelines where I want to utilize few stages (approx. 4 stages) from the 1 pipeline because code and functionality are similar.

Is there any way I can achieve this in the Azure DevOps YAML pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can export similar stages to a [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops), then you can use it in other pipelines with `extends`:

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
- master

extends:
  template: start.yml
  parameters:
    buildSteps:  
      - bash: echo Test #Passes
        displayName: succeed
      - bash: echo "Test"
        displayName: succeed
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: Test 3 - Will Fail
        inputs:
          script: echo "Script Test"
```

The template will be (for example):

```
# File: start.yml
parameters:
- name: buildSteps # the name of the parameter is buildSteps
  type: stepList # data type is StepList
  default: [] # default value of buildSteps
stages:
- stage: secure_buildstage
  pool: Hosted VS2017
  jobs:
  - job: secure_buildjob
    steps:
    - script: echo This happens before code 
      displayName: 'Base: Pre-build'
    - script: echo Building
      displayName: 'Base: Build'

    - ${{ each step in parameters.buildSteps }}:
      - ${{ each pair in step }}:
          ${{ if ne(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}:
            ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}       
          ${{ if eq(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}: 
            '${{ pair.value }}': error         

    - script: echo This happens after code
      displayName: 'Base: Signing'
```